# How to center the text in front of a coin as bg?

Tags: css

In this [page](http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in) I want to center the numbers in front of the coin. 
 Somebody please help me.

This is the html text in which 10 should have a centered golden coin as bg:

```
<div class="goldcoinbg">10</div>
```

This is the css code for the number text and the golden coin as bg:

```
#pghomepage .goldcoinbg {
background: url(http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/images/goldcoin.png) no-repeat center center;
width: 100px;
height: 102px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
color: yellow;
font-size: 80px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 1em 20% 5px 20%;
}
```

Comment: You should provide some code or example here. As soon as you fix this issue, your question will have no value to anyone else, because we won't know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="coin">1</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.coin { 
    background:url(http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/images/goldcoin.png);
    width:100px;
    height:102px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:70px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:gold;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:102px;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CjeyW/2/

Comment: @AgA Instead of the `vertical-align` property, I used `line-height` - just set it to the same value as the `height` property.

Comment: I salute your helping spirit!

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to get rid of your `height` property and simply add a padding of `50px`.

```
#pghomepage .goldcoinbg{
// Other styles

padding:50px;

// or to keep the coins in their current horizontal position:

padding-top:50px;
padding-bottom:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try manipulating your line-height property to be 2em or 3em and then a vertical-alignment: middle.  That may do the trick.

so it would be something like this:

```
.coin {
    line-height: 2em;
    vertical-alignment: middle;
}
```

fair warning.. this is from memory, you'll have to try it yourself, but you should have the bits you need to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `line-height` to the height of the div. In this case add:

```
line-height: 102px;
```

to `#pghomepage .goldcoinbg`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line-height to the height of the containing div.  In your case:

```
#pghomepage .goldcoinbg {
    background: url("http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/images/goldcoin.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    color: #FFFF00;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 102px;
    margin: 1em 20% 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 102px;
```